# searching a text file in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm having a text file with some urls and "-" sysmbols. I want to find whether there are urls which do not match the domain name which is given by the user? If it is so I have to print one message or else if it is only the given domain name and "-" symbols another message?How can I do this? Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import string

print 'Enter Your Domain Name'
domain = input()

foo = open('new.txt','r')
seen = set()
lines = foo.readlines()

for line in lines:
    match = re.search(domain,line)
    for line in lines:
    match = re.search(domain,line)
    if match: seen.add("Message1")
    else: seen.add('Message2')

foo.close()
```

sample text file:

```
http://www.mysite.com
-
http://www.mysite.com
http://www.yoursite.com
-
http://www.mysite.com
http://www.yoursite.com
```

Comment: Right now, the syntax for your code is invalid. Note that you have two `for` loops that say `for line in lines:`, and no indentation after the second `for` statement. Fix your code first, and then we can better help =D

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of your code! ;)
Try raw_input() instead of input()

If the line matches with the domain it is fine. Else match it with "-".

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

domain = raw_input('Enter Your Domain Name: ')

foo = open('new.txt','r')
lines = foo.readlines()
foo.close()

ok_count = 0
not_ok_count = 0

for line in lines:
    match = re.search(domain,line)
    if match:
        ok_count += 1
    else:
        match = re.search("-",line)
        if match:
            ok_count += 1
        else:
            not_ok_count += 1

if not_ok_count == 0:
    print "File contains valid domains"
else:
    print "File contains invalid domains"
```

Hope this helps!

Vivek